# Exitwp is unable to import PyYAML module

Tags: python, macos, pip, octopress, pyyaml

I'm in the process of migrating a blog from Wordpress to [Octopress](http://octopress.org). As a part of this process, I'm using a tool called [exitwp](https://github.com/thomasf/exitwp) to convert all Wordpress content to Markdown files.

I've followed the `exitwp` setup instructions and installed all the requirements. Python was installed using [homebrew](http://brew.sh); the Python modules were installed with `pip`. I'm on a Mac with OS X 10.9.

```
$ which python

/usr/bin/python

$ pip install --upgrade -r pip_requirements.txt

Requirement already up-to-date: html5lib==1.0b1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r pip_requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already up-to-date: beautifulsoup4==4.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r pip_requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already up-to-date: PyYAML==3.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r pip_requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already up-to-date: html2text==3.200.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r pip_requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from html5lib==1.0b1->-r pip_requirements.txt (line 1))

$ pip show PyYAML

Name: PyYAML
Version: 3.10
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: 

$ python -c "import sys; print sys.path"

['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

When I run `exitwp`, I get the following error:

```
$ cd ~/code/exitwp/
$ python exitwp.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exitwp.py", line 10, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

My thoughts are that this might have something to do with Python coming pre-installed with OS X, and that I have installed a newer version of Python via `homebrew`. I'm not very experienced with Python and `pip`, so I'm having some problems getting to the bottom of this.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you run `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` from your command line and post the output?

Comment: Thanks, @jazzpi. I've edited my question and added this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `python` executable searches in `/System/Library/Frameworks...` for modules. `pip` installed your modules to `/usr/local/lib/python2-7/site-packages` though

A quick and dirty solution would be do simply add `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to your PYTHONPATH:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH python exitwp.py
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Worked like a charm. Could adding the path to my `PATHONPATH` have any adverse side effects? What would be "the slow and clean way" to fix it? :)

Comment: @Leif: No, it shouldn't, since you're only setting the `PYTHONPATH` for the one command you're running (`python exitwp.py`). If you want it to be permanent, you'd have to export it. That could have side effects (being able to import modules from `/usr/local/...` somewhere else), but that would probably be positive, right?

Comment: Great, thanks again for the help and explanation. I will probably export it so that it's permanent, but I'll need to read up on that first; I need to understand what I'm doing first :)